# Java Code for Import Maven Project to Workspace

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin using swt. The plugin is responsible for generating a maven project and I need to import the created project to my workspace automatically via Java code. so what is the Java code to import a project to workspace?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried to find the source code but didn't find yet