# Java code for importing projects in workspace in Plug-in Development

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk

I am creating a plug-in using Eclipse plug-in development.
I want to know if there is any code in Java by which we can import projects in Package Explorer in the Eclipse instance.
I know this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765585/java-code-for-import-maven-project-to-workspace) but it hasn't been answered.

Comment: You don't import in to Package Explorer - you import in to the workspace. Import what - an existing Eclipse project from another workspace? Plain Java code? ...

Comment: @greg-449 yeah sorry. import into workspace. Yes import an existing eclipse project from anywhere. Also, can I open just a directory in the workspace, which may further have sub-directories and files?

Comment: There isn't a straightforward API for this. You would have to study the code in `org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.datatransfer.WizardProjectsImportPage` to see what it does.